# Transfer function of high order filter

Tags: transfer-function, passive-filter

[image]Hi
I have tried to extract the transfer function of the filter above, as you see it a high order filter.

I have combined the \$C_1\$ in parallel with \$R\$ & \$C_2\$ then make a voltage divider in order to add the inductor.
I always miss the capacitor or I don't get the same result. Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "always miss the capacitor"?

Comment: The given transfer function is correct - you can derive it using the voltage divider rule. However, the form is a bit "uncommon" (factor D identical to a capacitor). Recommendet form: D=1 and factor C=time constant.

Comment: above you can see the derivated transfer function, I have got completely different answers!!

Comment: Shouldn't the voltage gain actually be Z/sL+Z?

Comment: it is a voltage divider, isnt it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to MATLAB, I would recommend you try using a tool called [scam](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA6.html). Using a netlist, MATLAB will spit out the parameter values for your transfer function.

That being said if you're still interested in doing it manually, I don't see any issue with combining the resistor and second capacitor in series, putting that in parallel with the first capacitor and doing a voltage division. Any way you could show us your calculations, I'm kind of flying blind without seeing what exactly you tried.

Comment: please can you see above the calculation of transfer function

Answer (score 0):

The transfer function should be
$$
T(s) = \frac{1 + C_2 R s}{1 + C_2 R s + (C_1 L + C_2 L) s^2 + C_1 C_2 L R s^3}
$$
Your calculation of \$Z\$ is correct, however you made some mistake during the calculation of
$$
T(s) = \frac{Z}{sL + Z}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is different than the transfer function of the datasheet.

Comment: I'm confident that the derivation is correct. Maybe there is some typo in the datasheet. You can check by simulation. Just use some arbitrary values.